# How to update timestamps in mybatis?

Tags: java, oracle, sql-update, mybatis

In Oracle, we can update timestamp fields using a query like this - update dd_transactions set created_date = TIMESTAMP '2020-06-02 16:19:03.405 UTC'  where internal_id=5968000;
Note TIMESTAMP '2020.............'. How to do the same in mybatis?

CreationDate is a string in my POJO.

```
<update id="update"
        parameterType="com.optimal.directdebit.core.repository.domain.DdTransactions">
        update dd.transactions
        <set>
            created_date=#{creationDate, jdbcType=TIMESTAMP}   // does not work
            created_date=#{creationDate}  // does not work
        .................
```

.....................

Am I missing something here?

Comment: If the column type is `timestamp`, you need to remove the time zone part (=`UTC`) from the string. Then `#{creationDate}` should work. If you need to store time zone, the column type has to be `timestamp with time zone`.

Comment: What is the type of `creationDate` field? If `creationDate` is a Date or an Instant MyBatis should convert it into a TIMESTAMP automatically. If `creationDate` is a String then you need to change your SQL query properly to convert a string value into a TIMESTAMP.